# Fecha actual en Input

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente código para mostrar la fecha actual, pero muestra con una fecha posterior. Cómo solucionarlo, Gracias!

```
<input type="text" name="fecha_registro" id="fecha_actual" readonly value='<?php echo date('d-m-Y') ?>'>
```

Comment: Debes establecer la zona horaria con PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que has puesto está correcto, **el problema es la zona horaria del servidor**

**Hay dos formas de configurarlo**

**1. [Con php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file)**

Este archivo es el archivo de configuración para PHP

Como se explica:

1. Ejecute `phpinfo()` y busque Archivo de configuración cargado y abra el archivo `php.ini` mencionado en esa sección.
2. Cambie la configuración predeterminada de la zona horaria agregando su nueva zona horaria modificando esta línea: `date.timezone = Asia / Kolkata`.
3. Guarde el archivo php.ini y detenga el servidor Apache.
4. Reinicie el servidor Apache. La configuración de la zona horaria ahora debería modificarse.

---

**2. Con [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)**

Recibe:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier ) : bool
```

Lo cual quiere decir que recibe como string un parámetro y devuelve un bool (true o false)

Ejemplo:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/NewYork");
```

Puedes ver más en el manual (enlace anteriormente vinculado)